# Is there a good reason in C++ to refer to a property without changing it?

Tags: c++

I'm using someone else's C++ app as a guide for my own C# application and I've come across a strange pattern:

```
array[index].property;
```

No assignment. Nothing evaluated.

I assume this is a vestigial line, left over from when an assignment would have been done here.

But I'm not sure. And seeing as I'm having problems, I'm starting to turn over even the most unlikely rocks.

My question then: does that line do anything? Does it perhaps perform a function akin to [`touch`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29)?

---

**Update - real code**

The real code is:

```
devconfig[fbbloop-1].wAlphaMax;
```

Where `devconfig` is an array of the following struct:

```
typedef struct tagBIRDDEVICECONFIG
{
    BYTE    byStatus;           // device status (see bird device status bits, above)
    BYTE    byID;               // device ID code (see bird device ID's, above)
    WORD    wSoftwareRev;       // software revision of device
    BYTE    byError;            // error code flagged by device
    BYTE    bySetup;            // setup information (see bird device setup bits, above)
    BYTE    byDataFormat;       // data format (see bird data formats, above)
    BYTE    byReportRate;       // rate of data reporting, in units of frames
    WORD    wScaling;           // full scale measurement, in inches
    BYTE    byHemisphere;       // hemisphere of operation (see bird hemisphere codes, above)
    BYTE    byDeviceNum;        // bird number
    BYTE    byXmtrType;         // transmitter type (see bird transmitter type bits, above)
    WORD    wAlphaMin[7];       // filter constants (see Birdnet3 Protocol pp.26-27 for values)
    WORD    wAlphaMax[7];       // filter constants (see Birdnet3 Protocol pp.26-27 for values)
    WORD    wVM[7];             // filter constants (see Birdnet3 Protocol pp.26-27 for values)
    BIRDANGLES  anglesReferenceFrame;   // reference frame of bird readings
    BIRDANGLES  anglesAngleAlign;       // alignment of bird readings
}
BIRDDEVICECONFIG;
```

Comment: We may need to see more code.  What is the type of array?

Comment: OK, I'll update it. (To be honest, I thought this would be a shoot-down question.)

Comment: @kotlinski: really?? i though it was similar to c#

Comment: Since it isn't clear what it does do, it isn't good style, but without knowing what `array`, `index`, and `property` are we aren't going to be able to tell you.

Comment: Next question:  is the qualifier `volatile` attached to anything relevant?  That's the only way a plain memory access would do anything.

Comment: @David Nope, no volatiles anywhere.

Comment: @Kotlinski, if we're going to accept that there's such a thing as a "property" in C++, we've automatically opened the door to there being "get," too. In fact, both C++ Builder and C++/CLI *do* have properties, and they *do* have "get" accessors.

Comment: One reason to do something like this is to access a memory-mapped I/O register that has side effects when read. It must be declared volatile, and really should be accompanied by a comment to explain the side effects. It doesn't look like that's happening here, especially since the expression in the update evaluates to an array, not a fundamental type, so it won't cause anything to be read.

Comment: @Rob: I'm sorry but I just don't count those as C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you included fits a pattern that I call "This programmer is a goof rocket".  The code either does nothing or there is a side effect on which the programmer is depending.  In both cases, "This programmer is a goof rocket" is a good description of a programmer who codes like that.

The case of "oh, the previous coder just make a mistake" is mearly a nice variant of "This programmer is goof rocket".

Comment: Looks like you're right. (But now I feel bad in case the original programmer googles any of his old work!)

Comment: OK, humour a non-C++ person - what's wrong with `typedef struct tagFoo`?

Comment: Consider the name, "tagfoo".  In what way is that a meaningful name?

Comment: Ah, OK then. I thought we were referring to the general pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The original developer most likely ran into a bug with the compiler not recompiling some changed files.

This happens fairly often with Visual Studio, less often with more recent versions, when you change some central code and use minimal rebuilds.

Essentially, the compiler will not notice some change and link with old or incorrect object code. The result is some strange behavior that doesn't make sense and is nearly impossible to debug, i.e. a function returning to the wrong address or jumping into the middle of some other function for no apparent reason.

The solution to this is to do a full rebuild, but if the developer doesn't immediately know that this is a mistake on the compiler's side, they might think that the issue is in the code and try to fix it.

Often, introducing a code change that has no actual effect on the functionality of the code will fix the issue. It's also fairly common to see a line that's just `0;` used to achieve the same effect. Again, if the developer doesn't know that the issue was caused by the compiler, they might think that this line of code that does nothing is important.

Comment: Interesting you mention a line which is just `0;`. Another line in the code I'm looking at goes like this: `double ang[3];33;`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do much if the container is indeed an array and `index` is within array bounds. If the container is is a `map`, a record will be created for `index` key.

Answer (score 2):

No, unless the **operator []** was overloaded. Even so, it is a weird thing to do. Probably it is a leftover from something else.

Comment: Or if the whole thing was labeled `volatile`, in which case it's a memory access, possibly a memory-mapped I/O access or possibly a lame attempt at a memory fence.

Comment: @David: sick of you to come up with that... but true

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no function to that line. It's a primitive access, so no funky overloading shenanigans going on here. It could be covering up for some compiler bug or error, and it wouldn't be the first time I've seen nonsense lines have to be left in for that reason, but it certainly doesn't serve an actual purpose in the execution of the program.

Answer (score 1):

From your update it looks like the code is just accessing the address of the first item of an array.  You can safely remove the line.

Answer (score 1):

Often when you see nonsensical code like that, it was created because programmer wanted to supress some pedantic warning from either the compiler or some static analysis tool.

If you have access to the versioning system, you could maybe go back in time and see during which conditions when it was created...